# Monggomapper : Sort data with its Association Model's keys

Tags: sorting, mongodb, mongomapper, model-associations

This is basically a simple task, but I can't find a way how to perform a sort/order data in Mongomapper Model with keys that belongs from its association.

Like suppose I have two models :

```
class Product 
 include MongoMapper::Document

 key :name, String
 key :product_category_id, ObjectId

 belongs_to :product_category
end

class ProductCategory
 include MongoMapper::Document

 key :name, String, :required => true, :unique => true
end
```

All I want to do is simple get the data from 'Product' that sorted by its 'Product Category's Name'.. I've already tried :

```
Product.where(:name => /#{@keyword}/i).sort("product_category.name".to_sym)
```

but not working, and many others ways that perform an error in return :(...

Is anybody could help me to solve this ?? Really appreciate a lot...

Thanks

Regards, 
Ronny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in your question, Product and ProductCategory are mapped to separate collections in MongoDB.
As such, you cannot do a SQL join, sort, select, and unique.  MongoDB will not access more than one collection for a normal query.
You can sort the products in local memory, but this requires fetching both the products and their associated product_categories.

```
Products.all.sort{|a, b| a.product_category.name <=> b.product_category.name}
```

However, you can take advantage of embedding so that the data is all in one collection, and therefore easily sortable by MongoDB.

```
class Product
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  one :product_category
end

class ProductCategory
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  key :name, String
end
```

Note that ProductCategory is an EmbeddedDocument.
The test below shows a MongoMapper sort clause by 'product_category.name'.
Hope that this helps your understanding and progress.

test/unit/product_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Product.delete_all
  end

  test "association sort" do
    Product.create(name: 'Act of Valor', product_category: ProductCategory.new(name: 'movie'))
    Product.create(name: 'Oliver Twist', product_category: ProductCategory.new(name: 'book'))
    assert_equal(2, Product.count)

    products_by_db_order = Product.all.to_a
    assert_equal(['Act of Valor', 'Oliver Twist'], products_by_db_order.map(&:name))
    p products_by_db_order.map(&:name)

    products_by_category_order = Product.sort('product_category.name').to_a
    assert_equal(['Oliver Twist', 'Act of Valor'], products_by_category_order.map(&:name))
    p products_by_category_order.map(&:name)
  end
end
```

output

```
Run options: --name=test_association_sort

# Running tests:

["Act of Valor", "Oliver Twist"]
["Oliver Twist", "Act of Valor"]
.

Finished tests in 0.042368s, 23.6027 tests/s, 70.8082 assertions/s.

1 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Woaa.. Thanks a lot Gary:D, you save my day^^.. Its worked.. But I am a little bit curious about Mongomapper, when I used "Product.all" and then sort it using "sort{|a, b| a.product_category.name <=> b.product_category.name}" its working.. 

But when I used condition query like "Product.where(condition)", the "sort{|a, b| a.product_category.name <=> b.product_category.name}" function not working.. 

So my solution is when I used condition query, I must convert it to array with 'to_a' first and then used "sort{|a, b| a.product_category.name <=> b.product_category.name}"..

Thanks again Gary :D

Comment: The confusion is that you are calling the method "sort" on objects of different classes.  Try the following with the Rails console (rails c) just enter the first part up to .class -- Product.all.class => Array, Product.where.class => Plucky::Query, Product.sort.class => Plucky::Query, Product.sort.to_a.class => Array.  So Product.all.sort is calling Array#sort, and Product.where.sort is calling Plucky::Query#sort.  You have to finish your query with one of the finder methods to generate an actual DB query and return results.

Comment: Oo I see.. Now I get it why :D.. Thanks a lot for helping me:)

Comment: Glad to help.  Seems like you like the answer, please click to accept it and our bot will close out the ticket for me.